# Changing forked repository

Tags: git, github

There is repository B which I forked from, original repository A. There are many commits I made on B. However, I am only supposed to send pull requests to repository A' which is also a forked repository of A.

Can I change my original forked repo? I noticed that since I have forked from A, I am not allowed to fork from A' (it redirects to B). I understand that sending a pull request to A is possible from github, but I want this to be visible on github as B is forked from A'. How do I do that without deleting current repo (B) and re-forking from A' and (maybe) manually redoing all commits ? Why am I not able to fork from A' while B is still there?

Comment: Fork B' from A' and push from your working repo to B', switch the origin around as per @nash_ag

Comment: Forking B' from A' redirects to B (as explained in question)

Comment: All your changes in your local repo, just delete the original fork.

Comment: And the change the remote and push? Would that work?

Comment: Can't think why not. Commits matter, not repos.  I'd fetch first.  Your backout plan is just re-fork A.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub doesn't expose a user interface to do this. You can contact GitHub support, explain to them the situation, and they can fix it for you manually. They are friendly and pretty fast (give it a day or 2), even if you don't have a paid subscription with them.

Comment: They responded and got it fixed within a few hours !! For anyone looking for reference, reach them at support@github.com

Answer (score 0):

You change the target using:

```
git remote set-url upstream <git://repo_address>
```